# mysql trigger using custom function

Tags: mysql, function, triggers

I am trying to write a MySQL trigger that, upon update of a row, will call a custom function (which works fine outside of the trigger) and update a column in the table the trigger is on.

```
BEGIN  
UPDATE candles 
       SET can_materials_cost = (SELECT calculateMaterialCost(NEW.can_id)  
       WHERE candles.can_id = NEW.can_id);  
END
```

I've written basic audit style triggers that upon update save the old value into a different table, but for some reason when trying to use my custom function I receive an error stating:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE candles.can_id = NEW.can_id);
END' at line 4

The custom function performs:

```
BEGIN
-- This function assumes that the raw wax cost is for 20kg bags only - BEWARE!
DECLARE result DECIMAL(10,2);
SET result = (
    (select calculateWaxCost(_can_id))
    +
    (select calculateDyeCost(_can_id))
    +
    (select calculateScentCost(_can_id)));
RETURN result;
END
```

Comment: I wonder if it's a good idea to have this much business logic in the database. Could become a nightmare to maintain.